# U and the end of vector in iSIM

Tags: vhdl, simulation, xilinx, ise

I am making first steps in VHDL and ISE (from Xilinx).

I've tried to create a simple 16bit -> 32bit converter.
Converter receives a compliment to 2 number (16bit, so it is 1 bit for sign and 15 bits for modulus number) and outputs its 32bit form.

I've written such a piece of code in VHDL:

```
library IEEE;
--using standard lib
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--lib provides arithmetic functions for vectors
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
--using lib for operating on U2-code numbers
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;


entity MB_16b_to_32_conv is
    Port ( X_16b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (16-1 downto 0);
           Y_32b : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (32-1 downto 0));
end MB_16b_to_32_conv;

architecture Behavioral of MB_16b_to_32_conv is

begin

 Y_32b <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(X_16b), 32-1));

end Behavioral;
```

running a simulation in Xilinx ISE gives me an error:
input is "0000000000000101"
and output is "0000000000000101U" (orange in iSIM).

When converted to decimal in iSIM i get input = 5 and output = U.
I don't know why there is U and how to get rid of it, so I am looking for help.

Answer (score 1):

You have this situation because you have an error in your assignment

```
Y_32b <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(X_16b), 32-1));
```

You expanded x_16b upto **32-1** (31 bit) and one bit stays undefined so you received U in the bit of the bus. You have to expand X_16b upto **32** bits, try it as follow:

```
Y_32b <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(X_16b), 32));
```

And it should work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the difference but the fix is that there should be

```
Y_32b <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(X_16b), Y_32b'length);
```

instead of

```
Y_32b <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(X_16b), 32-1));
```

although Y_32b'length is 31 I think...

Comment: When writing source code, *spelling is paramount*. A user should be able to copy-and-paste your code without introducing new, unrelated issues. Please take the time to proofread your answers.

Comment: Why would `Y_32b'length` be anything other than 32, anyway?

Comment: it is equal to 31, not 32

Comment: Clearly it is not, or else your solution wouldn't work. Think carefully: If you have N objects, numbered 0 through 31, what is the value of N?